# how to uninstall vscode with apt

Tags: apt, software-installation, uninstall

I installed Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu using:

```
sudo apt install ./code_1.37.1-1565886362_amd64.deb
```

I then found these commands to try to find out more information about the package:

```
dpkg -l dirmngr
systemctl --user status dirmngr
apt-cache search code
```

I still see it on my ubuntu application gui but I can't find it in the uninstall options. I also tried erasing the .deb file. What tools can I use to see these package details? 
How do I fully remove this installed program?
Is there a folder that .deb files install into? Will it show up in /bin?

Comment: `dpkg-query -s code` is a possibility

Comment: To install `deb` packages use `dpkg -i <package>` or `gdebi <package>`.

Comment: The `.deb` file is an archive containing 3 files, one of which is a compressed tarball of all the files to install into /usr/bin, /usr/share etc. Once the program is installed then you don't need the deb file anymore. To uninstall you should be able to say `apt remove code`. I have no idea why you are asking about the `dirmngr` which is the server for X.509 certificates if you want info about `code`.

Comment: Thank you. I'd love to find more information on the folders and files used in the installation process. Also, I'd like to learn more about environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also very confused by seeing `dirmngr` as the pattern you searched for.

1.However, in case you ever have a `.deb` file that you installed but don't know what actual package it corresponds to you can run `dpkg-deb -W`.

Just to illustrate, using `epson-printer-utility_1.0.2.deb` as an example:

```
 $ ls *.deb
 epson-printer-utility_1.0.2.deb

 $ sudo dpkg-deb -W epson-printer-utility_1.0.2.deb
 epson-printer-utility  1.0.2-1lsb3.2
```

2.What is interesting is that trying to figure out what package got installed from the original .deb filename is never a good idea, because if you just make a copy and give it a different name :

```
$ cp epson-printer-utility_1.0.2.deb abcde.deb

$ sudo dpkg-deb -W abcde.deb
epson-printer-utility   1.0.2-1lsb3.2
```

3.And finally if you ever want to find all the info from a given .deb, and especially whether you have that particular package already installed, you can run `sudo dpkg-query -s [package name given by dpkg-deb]` or in one step (replace "abcde.deb" by your .deb file, put in "" if it has spaces):

```
sudo dpkg-query -s $(dpkg-deb -f abcde.deb | grep "Package" | cut -d: -f2)

Package: epson-printer-utility
Status: install ok installed
Priority: extra
Section: alien
Installed-Size: 10652
Maintainer: Seiko Epson Corporation <linux-printer@epson.jp>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.0.2-1lsb3.2
Depends: lsb (>= 3.2)
Description: Epson Printer Utility for Linux
```

### Update

For the final command one can "usually" also use a slightly shortened version:

```
dpkg-query -s $(dpkg-deb -W abcde.deb |cut -f1)
```

**as long** as someone doesn't go crazy and create a package with a `[TAB]` inserted in the name, because with <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> a filename can actually be made to look like this:

```
$ cp abcde.deb "abc  de.deb"
$ ls 
'abc'$'\t''de.deb'   abcde.deb
```

Yet it will still work just as intended:

```
$ dpkg-deb -W 'abc'$'\t''de.deb' 
epson-printer-utility   1.0.2-1lsb3.2
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Where would be a good place to find documentation on the dpkg command?

Comment: `dpkg` is a beast of a package,  I would still recommend you install all the `dpkg-*` packages, because as time goes on you will find more and more uses for all the various commands that begin with `dpkg-` . As far as documentation/overview/tutorial for `dpkg` as well as package management in Debian, I recommend [link]https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/packaging-tutorial/packaging-tutorial.en.pdf[/link]. Also, while you cannot upvote answers yet, please accept the answer by clicking the button below the two arrows if you found it helpful, that way others in the future will see it. thanks

Comment: Thank you, BarBar1234, thats a great resource. How about documentation for ```curl```? I installed the IBM_cloud_cli using ```curl -fsSL https://clis.cloud.ibm.com/install/linux | sh``` However, I could not use ```dpkg``` to find information on this installation. Is this a different package manager? Is this better that using .deb instillations?

Comment: `curl` is a URL puller/downloader. In your case `IBM_cloud_cli` is NOT a package, but a BASH script (easily identifyable by #!/bin/bash as the first line). the `sh` command is responsbile for executing the script. If you run `file linux` in the same folder where you downloaded that file, it will tell you that it is a `linux: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable` as opposed to `epson-printer-utility_1.0.2.deb: Debian binary package ` for my example above. A script is comparable to a short windows BATCH file (.bat extension) while a package would be comparable to a program installation.