# Removing a program installed via apt and a .deb

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I installed `browsh` via `apt install` (I followed the instructions below):

`sudo apt install ./browsh_1.6.4_linux_amd64.deb`

`rm ./browsh_1.6.4_linux_amd64.deb`

(This is after I used wget to grab the .deb file).

I'd like to remove `browsh` from my Ubuntu (WSL) install, but `sudo apt remove browsh` yields only a `E: Unable to locate package browsh`. I'm guessing I have to manually remove it, but I can't find where the binary lives. Is there a default location for .deb files installed via apt?

Comment: What does `apt search browsh` show?

Comment: The filename may well have no relation to the package name. Maybe grab the deb file again and use `dpkg -I` to get the package details.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you have a `.deb` file installed, but cannot pinpoint the exact corresponding package name, you can use `dpkg-deb -W [.deb package]` like so:

```bsh
$ sudo dpkg-deb -W browsh_1.6.4_linux_amd64.deb
browsh  1.6.4
```

However, as I have explained in [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537110/how-to-uninstall-vscode-with-apt/537153#537153](http://[https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537110/how-to-uninstall-vscode-with-apt/537153#537153][https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537110/how-to-uninstall-vscode-with-apt/537153#537153])
 , doing just that is hardly foolproof, because even changing the name of the `.deb` will not affect the underlying packages that get installed. The link actually describes some really insane but still valid filenames (hidden tab chars that get transformed to their corresponding codes etc.)

**Clearly, `browsh` by itself is not found by `apt remove` in your case**. How can that be? We need to dig a little deeper.

There are several things to try (as long as you did not happen to install a malformed or spoofed `deb` which you then deleted afterwards, you may be looking for a needle in a haystack i.e. removing some other valid package etc). Since you specifically want to get rid of `browsh` and not the effective package installed by the `.deb` file you can use:

```bsh
$ sudo dpkg-query -S browsh
browsh: /usr/local/bin/browsh
```

It strangely enough gets installed to `/usr/local/bin` instead of `/usr/bin/` but to remove it just use

```bsh
$ sudo dpkg --simulate --purge browsh
```

Get rid of `simulate` to actually purge it.